# oauth.json file in GAE Youtube DATA API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, youtube, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I been confused when ask this file, because I don't know where I can get it, and I'm following the tutorial explained in here
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#upload_a_video

I'm really stuck in this part if anyone can help me I'll be thankful

```
def get_authenticated_service(args):

    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
        scope=YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE,
        message=MISSING_CLIENTS_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

    storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])       
    credentials = storage.get()
```

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in the comments at the sample whose URL you quote, about "populating the client_secrets.json file" using https://console.developers.google.com/ ?  Plenty of links in those comments and you tell us nothing about what you have done, what has resulted, in what way or sense are you stuck...?!

Comment: Am yesterday I was so obsess with this, I wasn't thinking clearly and that's leave me to that, but yeah I already have try what you say and it doesn't work for me, thanks anyway